# add a space every 2 charaters in a string

Tags: string, tcl

I have mac addresses in this shape "001122334455" that I want to turn into "00 11 22 33 44 55". I guess there is a way to do this in one line, but the only way I found is the following ridiculously horrible proc. Can someone show me how to do this properly ?

```
proc addSpaces { mac } {
    set mac [split $mac {}]                                  
    set i 0                                                  
    while { $i < 12 } {                                      
        if { [expr $i % 2] == 0 } {                          
            append macAddr " "                               
            append macAddr [lindex $mac $i]                  
            append macAddr [lindex $mac [expr $i + 1]]       
        }                                                    
        incr i                                               
    }
    return $macAddr                                                        
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use tcl's incredibly flexible `foreach`:

```
foreach {a b} [split $mac {}] {
    append macAddr " $a$b"
}
```

Or if you want to get rid of the leading space, construct a list instead of a string:

```
foreach {a b} [split $mac {}] {
    lappend macAddr "$a$b"
}
join $macAddr " "
```

Alternatively you can just `string trim` your string before returning

Comment: I forgot that foreach could do this kind of things :) The first one with a string trim is perfect.

Answer (score 4):

regsub also works

```
set s 001122334455
set t [string trimright [regsub -all {..} $s {& }]]
puts ">$t<"
```

```
>00 11 22 33 44 55<
```

---

@Donal's suggestion is great:

```
set t [join [regexp -all -inline .. $s]]  ;# "00 11 22 33 44 55"
```

Comment: Or `regexp -all -inline .. $s`